# StatsD not listening (port 8125)

Tags: logstash, graphite, statsd

Me and a colleague try to connect Logstash, Statsd, Graphite( & Grafana).

We set up every config file like we think is right, and logstash should send the output to Statsd. Statsd just isn't listening on port 8125.
When I run sudo service statsd start, it says it is already running. But when I do a netstat -an | grep 8125, no output is shown.

EXTRA: I can't seem to find the reference to the log of statsd (/var/log/statsd/statsd.log). Where can this be changed?

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you sure you've configured Statsd correctly? Try starting it directly from the command line in the foreground instead of a start script. Does the process show up in a "ps aux" list?

Answer (score 0):

Does the command `lsof -i :8125` give you back something ? In case not, did you correctly set the listenning port in `statsd/config.js` ? Mine is like this (I use influxdb backend) :

```
{
  port: 8125,
  backends: [ "./backends/graphite", "statsd-influxdb-backend" ]
}
```

Regarding your question about logs, actually, I didn't find any issue too...
In the exampleconfig.js, the config should be something like :

```
{
  log: {
    backend : ['path/to/logfile']
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work for me. StatsD fails to start. Help would be appreciate.

Comment: I just reinstalled StatsD the next day, and then it starts up with no problem at all.